# How to add change color of jquery progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

Use Case:-
Actually, I want to use multiple progress bars on the same page and I want to have each progress bar with a different color.
I know we can modify "ui-progressbar-value" CSS class but that makes the color modified for all the progress bars in that page.
So is there a way to achieve progress bars with multiple colors.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI ProgressBar functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      
      <style>
         .ui-widget-header {
            background: #cedc98;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            color: #333333;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
    .ui-progressbar-value{
        background: yellow !important;
    }
      </style>
      
      <script>
         $(function() {
            var progressbar = $( "#progressbar-2" );
            $( "#progressbar-2" ).progressbar({
               value: 30,
               max:30,
                classes: {
    "ui-progressbar-value": "test"
  }
            }).addClass('test');
            function progress() {
               var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;
               progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );
               if ( val < 99 ) {
                  setTimeout( progress, 100 );
               }
            }
            
            var progressbar2 = $( "#progressbar-3" );
            $( "#progressbar-3" ).progressbar({
               value: 30,
               max:30
            }).addClass("trst");
            function progress() {
               var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;
               progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );
               if ( val < 99 ) {
                  setTimeout( progress, 100 );
               }
            }
            setTimeout( progress, 3000 );
         });
         $('#progressbar-2').css({background: '#9CFF29'});
            
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
     <p>
     Progress 1
     </p>
       <div id = "progressbar-2" class="test"></div>
           <p>
     Progress 2
     </p>
      <div id = "progressbar-3"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: Modifying the link @Deepak

Comment: check my code,hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
            var progressbar = $( "#progressbar-2" );
            $( "#progressbar-2" ).progressbar({
               value: 30,
               max:30,
                classes: {
    "ui-progressbar-value": "test"
  }
            }).addClass('test');
            function progress() {
               var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;
               progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );
               if ( val < 99 ) {
                  setTimeout( progress, 100 );
               }
            }
            
    var progressbar2 = $( "#progressbar-3" );
            $( "#progressbar-3" ).progressbar({
               value: 30,
               max:30
            }).addClass("trst");
            function progress() {
               var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;
               progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );
               if ( val < 99 ) {
                  setTimeout( progress, 100 );
               }
            }
            setTimeout( progress, 3000 );
         });
         $('#progressbar-2').css({background: '#9CFF29'});
```

```css
.ui-widget-header {
            background: #cedc98;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            color: #333333;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
 #progressbar-2 > .ui-progressbar-value{
    background: green !important;
}
 #progressbar-3 > .ui-progressbar-value{
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI ProgressBar functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   </head>
   
   <body>
     <p>
     Progress 1
     </p>
       <div id = "progressbar-2" class="test"></div>
           <p>
     Progress 2
     </p>
      <div id = "progressbar-3"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Ref Css child selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator . For the first progress bar use

```
 #progressbar-2 > .ui-progressbar-value{
    background: green !important;
}
```

For the second use

```
 #progressbar-3 > .ui-progressbar-value{
    background: yellow!important;
}
```